# Ошибка TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript, odbc

```
import odbc = require('../../node_modules/odbc');

export default class Database {
    private static connectionString = "...";

    public static async executeScalar(sql: string): Promise<number> {
        const connection = await odbc.connect(Database.connectionString);
        const answer = await connection.query(sql);

        return answer[0][answer.columns[0].name]; // Ошибка
    }
}
```

```
Функция odbc.Connection.query(sql) возвращает
odbc.Result<unknown> (в JS это generic тип) в нем:
  по индексу (number) - строка ответной таблицы (тот самый unknown, но по идее {string, any}):
  поле columns - список столбцов (odbc.ColumnDefinition[]) в каждом элементе:
    dataType - тип данных, согласованный с SQL (number)
    name - имя столбца (string)
```

Пробовал поместить значение `answer.columns[0].name` в переменную с типом `any`, и только затем передавать переменную в качестве индекса, но не помогло (string в тексте ошибки изменилось на any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя пару часов поисков нашел следующее решение:
нужно явно определить тип данных для переменной `answer`, чтобы вместо стандартного `odbc.Result<unknown>` было `odbc.Result<{[index:string]:any}>`, тогда все будет прекрасно работать.